# How can i animate a String property in unity Animator?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I am creating an animation in my Unity Game using Playable Directors and Animators, and i need to animate the contents of a TextMeshPro so it changes its text within keyframe, but there is no Text property in the animator.

I initialy thought that this was just with TextMeshPro, and changed my component to a normal Text component. No property found either.

My last try was to create a new script called TextAnimator, and a string property that changes the TextMeshPro contents in editor using the [ExecuteInEditMode] annotation.
But when i tried to animate THIS property, it doesnt show up either!

Here is my component in game:

[image]

Here is when i try to add the string property:
[image]

Here is the TextAnimator:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class TextAnimator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TextMeshProUGUI textUI;
    [TextArea]
    public string text;
    void Update()
    {
        if (textUI) {
            textUI.text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that Unity can't animate strings at all, why is that? And what can i do as a workaround to make my animations?

Comment: as you said, afaik unity itself does not provide the ability to animate text, there are obviously assets in the store that provides this ability for [money](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/text-animator-for-unity-158707?q=text%20animation&orderBy=1). Otherwise i guess you need to write it yourself

Comment: You could add animation events that call a method that manipulates the text.

Comment: Every change in a text causes a repaint of the canvas .. so usually you try to keep UI updates to a minimum => it is not good practices to set the text every frame .. the animator would have the same "Problem"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep your initial TextMeshPRO and **change** the value of the **text** with a **method** with **animation events**.

You'll have to create a method to change your text. You can create a new class or use an existing one attached to your object.

```cs
using TMPro;

public class TextHelper {
    // You pass the reference of your text in the inspector
    public TMP_Text textObject;

    // You call this with an animation event
    public void SetText(string newText) {
        textObject.text = newText;
    }
}
```

Let's say you want your text to be "Hello" and then, at the middle of some animation, it automatically changes to "Goodbye".

1. Youl'll set your text to "Hello" in the inspector.
2. Then, you'll go to your animation and, at the middle of it, instead of changing the string in the inspector, you will **add an animation event** and **pass the string of your new text** as parameter.

For more information about animation events, see [this blog](https://bootcamp.uxdesign.cc/tip-of-the-day-unity-animation-events-2ad2526790a9) where it is explained. Note that you *can* have 1 parameter in a method called by animation.

Here is an example of how the animation event would look in the inspector. I'm using an animation event to call a method that plays a SFX by name:
[Example of animation event in inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwONg.png)

Official documentation is a little outdated, I think.

I hope that helps.

If, in the other hand, what you want is to make your text appear like RPG's, that's another story and I would recommend creating a dedicated script for it.

Answer (score -2):

There is a simple solution without code. Consider using **DOTween** asset as alternative. Just add "DOTWeen Animation" component to your text object, set the animation type to "Text" and write the sentence that should gradually appear in "To" input field. [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qH6s.png)